# Large numbers to string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

When I do the following:

```
alert((2053716830872415770228778006271971120334843128349550587141047275840274143041).toString());
```

I get the "2.053716830872415e+75" exponential notation.
I want to alert the number as is.
I tried toFixed(), toPrecision() and toLocaleString() and they output the same thing.

How can I accomplish this?
Note: the number is a variable, so I cannot alert("208..");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript [uses 64-bit floating point numbers](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5).
It is impossible to precisely store your value in a Javascript number.

Instead, you should use a BigInteger library.

- http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html
- http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/
- https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum

Comment: Are there any arbitrary-precision arithmetic JavaScript libraries out there?

Comment: Of those three libraries, the last one definitely seems the most "modern" in terms of implementation style.