# Solving Project Euler 16 with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on Project Euler, writing solutions in JavaScript. However, it seems Problem 16 cannot be solved with Javascript:

> 2<sup>15</sup> = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.
>
> What is the sum of the digits of the number 2<sup>1000</sup>?

Because JavaScript's 64bit precision isn't big enough to hold the number, calculating `Math.pow(2, 1000)` gives `1.0715086071862673e+301`. Obviously, I can't use this value to solve the problem because it doesn't contain all the digits of 2<sup>1000</sup>.

Is there another way to solve this problem? Note that I am *not* asking [how to get around the precision issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985153/large-numbers-to-string-in-javascript); however, if that's the only solution, so be it.

Ideally, I'd like to find an alternate solution (maybe a super-epic math approach?) to the problem.

<sub>(as an side note, i'm not trying to cheat and wean the answer out of SO. I've solved it, but I had to use Python)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to solve this by a naive approach of storing 2^1000 in an array (of digits). Runs in less than a second. Original idea from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/23305/#CH_zTmde10437a00).

```
var number = [1],
    sum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var overflow = 0,
        count = number.length + 1

    for(var j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        var digit = number[j] || 0;

        digit = 2 * digit + overflow;

        if(digit > 9)
        {
            digit -= 10;
            overflow = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            overflow = 0;
        }

        number[j] = digit;
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    sum += number[i];
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

check out a question I asked earlier:
[summing exponents in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272185/summing-exponents-in-javascript)

The response talks about BigNumber in JavaScript. That should help you get around the precision shortfalls in JavaScript when dealing with large numbers.

Comment: Like I (sort of) mentioned in my question, i'd like to avoid this kind  of solution if possible, but if that's the only way, so be it. +1 for now, if nothing better crops up after a day or so i'll mark as answered