# How do I add 1 to a big integer represented as a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I add 1 to this string in JavaScript?

```
var message = "12345612345678901234567890";
```

I want the output like this:

```
"12345612345678901234567891"
```

I tried this:

```
var message = "12345612345678901234567890";
message = parseInt(message);
var result = message + 1;
```

But `parseInt` returned a value in scientific notation like 1.234567896453e+25.

Comment: You obviously need a third-party arbitrary precision library. Are you using an environment where you can install one, such as Node?

Comment: `parseInt(message) + 1` isn't it?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma won't work, numbers are too big. MAX_SAFE_INTEGER in JavaScript is 9007199254740991.

Comment: For a string that big you have to use a library for precision, but normally you can cast your string as number `Number(message)`

Comment: You're right @JaredSmith.

Comment: String-based: `message.slice(0, -1) + '1'`

Comment: @hindmost won't work for arbitrary additions, wonder if that's what the OP wants?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985153/large-numbers-to-string-in-javascript) might help you, OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large numbers to string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985153/large-numbers-to-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @Jared Smith Work for given question. Nobody knows what the OP actually wants

Comment: @hindmost fair enough.

Comment: Surely arbitrary addition can be assumed as a requirement.  I mean, otherwise `return "12345612345678901234567891"` would count as "answering the question".

Comment: I added what i tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the big integer library [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) to add large numbers.

```js
var message = "12345612345678901234567890";

var messageAsNumber = bigInt(message);
var messagePlusOne = messageAsNumber.add('1');

console.log(messagePlusOne.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://peterolson.github.io/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can i do this without library??

Comment: No, you can't (Unless you take bits and pieces from the library and rewrite it yourself). This is not something that supported by normal javascript.

Comment: I already done with this library but i want to do it without library support.

Comment: Well then you should have asked that question instead.

Comment: @KevinPatel _"Can i do this without library??"_ Yes, it is possible derive correct sum without a library. You can segment initial string into `.length`s of `3` within an array, determine if number to add added to segment of three is greater than `1000`. If `true`, increment previous segment of `3` by `1`, set current segment of `3` to `000`. The approach can be adjusted to add appropriate number to previous index of array, and current array, to sum to, for example, `5123` if adding `124` to `4999`. See approach at Answer

Comment: Since 2019, there is support for `BigInt` in most browsers. That means you can accomplish this with `(BigInt(123122348903) + BigInt(1)).toString()`

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use libraries (2022), you can just use JS [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) object

```
let message = "12345612345678901234567890";
let messageBigInt = BigInt(message);
console.log(messageBigInt + BigInt(1)); // 12345612345678901234567891n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array from the string in `.length`s of `3` beginning from the end of the string.

Use a pattern which checks if adding `1` would result in the index of the array as a number would sum to `1000`, if `true`, increment previous array index by `1` and fill the current array index with `"000"`.

The pattern below only checks and adjusts last two elements of array; the same pattern can be extended to check each index of array, to properly adjust one or more of the indexes to `"000"` and increment the previous index by `1`.

```js
let message1 = "12345612345678901234567890";
let message2 = "12345612345678901234567999";
let message3 = "12345612345678901234999999";

function addNumberToString(str, numToAdd, digits = []) {

  const [N, len, max] = [3, str.length, 1000];

  for (let i = -N, l = len; digits.length < len / N; i -= N, l -= N) {
    digits.unshift(str.slice(i, l));
  }

  function add(m) {
    if (+digits[digits.length - m] + numToAdd < max) {
      let n = +digits[digits.length - m];
      digits[digits.length - m] = String(Number(n + numToAdd));
    } else {
      const M = m + 1;
      if (+digits[digits.length - M] + numToAdd < max) {
        let n = +digits[digits.length - M];
        digits[digits.length - M] = String(Number(n + numToAdd));
        digits[digits.length - (M - 1)] = "0".repeat(N);
      } else {
          if (digits[digits.length - (m + 1)]) {
            digits[digits.length - (M - 1)] = "0".repeat(N);
            add(m + 1);
          }
      }
    }
    return digits.join("")
  }
  return add(1);

}

console.log(
  addNumberToString(message1, 1)   
, addNumberToString(message2, 1)
,  addNumberToString(message3, 1)
);
```