# How to solve the issue of round number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, accounting

I am having an issue in which if I am entering 9 sixteen times and formatting it using accounting js or even `Math.round(9999999999999999)` it is becoming `10000000000000000`. How do I solve this issue .

Reference to accounting js or help me some the issue with `math.random` also.

http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

Comment: I suggest you get acquainted with MDN docs about `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). I think that is connected with some restrictions about length integers numbers.

Comment: you might want to read [this](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/javascripts-number-type-8d59199db1b6)

Comment: Do you get the value as a string? What is expected result? See also [How do I add 1 to a big integer represented as a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614407/how-do-i-add-1-to-a-big-integer-represented-as-a-string-in-javascript/)

Comment: https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/

Comment: It will be great if you can create an example for me . I am not able to do it thanks

Answer (score 4):

Floating point can't precisely represent all numbers. You'll ee this in integers as soon as your numbers are above `9,007,199,254,740,991` (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Beyond `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1` (9007199254740992), the `IEEE-754` floating-point format can no longer represent every consecutive integer because you no longer have a 1s bit; the lowest-order bit now represents multiples of `2`. Eventually, if we keep going, we lose that bit and only work in multiples of `4`. And so on.

Your values are well above that threshold, and so they get rounded to the nearest representable value.

Comment: How do I solve this in JavaScript , coz I have a requirement for to store it as same as 9 sixteen times

Comment: How about using the value a million times larger and adjust the display? Watch out for maximum value of floating number, though.

Comment: The thing is I am making use of accounting js to formatMoney method on blur event and unformatMoney on keydown event at that time when i pass the value 9999999999999999 to unformatMethod , it becomes 10000000000000000. So I need to solve this